# FB Instant Articles Comments, Like, Share

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-instant-articles

We are having difficulty getting the "Comment" and "Like" links to show up at the bottom our development instant articles.  We have enabled the option "Show on articles" under feedback settings but it still won't work.  The "Comment" and "Like" links do however show up for images.

We even tried to manually add the tag `<meta property="fb:likes_and_comments" content="enable">` and that too didn't work.

Any thoughts on what could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try

- Click 'Publishing Tools' at the top of your Page.
- Click 'Configuration' under 'Instant Articles' in the left
  navigation bar
- Scroll down to the 'Tools' panel, select 'Feedback Settings,' and set
  your preferences on showing or not showing the feedback buttons.

referring to:https://developers.facebook.com/ia/blog/post/2016/06/28/update-to-like-comment-share